# Weird increase of url visited reported in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, 404, iframe

Oddly, there has been lately a very significant increase of 404 errors detected in Google Console Insights for some website I run.

I checked Google Analytics for that website: the URLs that give the 404 errors are displayed in the 'Home' section, under the heading 'What pages do your users visit? '.

The numerous URLs that give the 404 errors are displayed as  '/[object HTMLIFrameElement]' and '/[object Window]'

Here is a screenshot from the Google Analytics homepage:

[image]

> What does it mean? Is is a bot trying to reach non-existent pages?

---

#Update

Here is a screenshot of the table displayed in Google Analytics' Site Content:

[image: table in Google Analytics' Site content]

Comment: I noticed it's HTMLi.  Just wondering.  Does "HTMLIFrameElement" stand for HTMLi  FrameElement or HTML iFrame ELement?  When I googled "'htmli' definition computer" there were several references to html injection.

Comment: @Manube Do you have _iframes_ or code that open windows (e.g., popups)? If so, it appears these might be returning `404` errors.

Comment: @Trebor: it is HTML iFrame ELement

Comment: @dan: there are some iframes, but they do not open new windows or popup. One of them is a third-party video, the other contains HTML, with a link to the main website

Comment: @Manube I did not mean that did _both_. Use the [Live URL Test](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289?hl=en#test_live_page&zippy=%2Curl-status-live-test) tool to see if there are any issues with those.